# codeigniter rest api authentication not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

I am using CI3 and chriskacerguis rest server library for api.

I have config rest

```
...
$config['rest_auth'] = 'digest';
...
$config['auth_source'] = '';
...
$config['rest_valid_logins'] = ['admin' => '1234', 'user' => 'test'];
```

When I try to get data using browser I get authentication popup even when I enter correct login detail its keep on pop, I think it is not getting validated.

What is correct way to make it authenticate that use rest_valid_logins detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your rest authentication like this.

```
$config['rest_auth'] = 'basic';
```

Then when you are prompted to enter credentials on a popup, Type what you set on your valid_logins setting.

For example

```
Username: admin
Password: 1234
```